# Error when writing to a compressed CSV file in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, gzip

I am trying to write data (contained in a dict) to a compressed (gzip) CSV file. As far as I understand the [gzip.GzipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) method should accept a writing operation as a normal file object. Such as:

```
   import gzip
   import csv

   with gzip.GzipFile(filename="test.csv.gz", mode="a") as gziphdlr:
       writer = csv.DictWriter(gziphdlr, fieldnames=['time','value'])
       writer.writeheader()
       writer.writerow({'time': 0.1, "value": 100})
       writer.writerow({'time': 0.2, "value": 200})
```

However, I get the error:

```
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 154, in writerow 
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/gzip.py", line 285, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
  TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any suggestions where I may be wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't use `gzip` as your variable name, you're redefining the `gzip` module.

Comment: By default, the inner file in gzip is opened in binary mode. To use text mode (what the `csv` module outputs) you need `mode='at'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a buffer text stream like [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

```
import gzip
import csv
import io

# Take care using append mode to not write headers multiple times
with gzip.GzipFile(filename='test.csv.gz', mode='w') as gzip:
    buf = io.TextIOWrapper(gzip, write_through=True)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(buf, fieldnames=['time', 'value'])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'time': 0.1, 'value': 100})
    writer.writerow({'time': 0.2, 'value': 200})
```

Try to load data with `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv.gz')
print(df)

# Output
   time  value
0   0.1    100
1   0.2    200
```